# Error with printout of functions C++

Tags: c++, function, inheritance

I am currently doing a program for school and it's the first time i've used inheritance in it. My issue is that I am getting these errors from Visual Studio when attempting to print out.
C2296: << illegal, left operand has type of 'const char[7]'
and
C2297: << illegal, right operand has type of 'const std::string *'

my print line is :

```
    string printOutput = "Book #" << &getCallNumber() << ", title: " << &getTitle() << " by " << &getAuthor() << " pages: " << getNumPages() << ", status: " << getStatus() << ", fees: " /*<< getFees()*/;
```

and the function definitions are as follows:

```
    const string &getCallNumber() const {
    return callNumber;
}

    const string &getTitle() const {
    return title;
}

    const string &Book::getAuthor() const 
{
    return author;
}

    int Book::getNumPages() const 
{
    return numPages;
}

    Status getStatus() const {
    return status;
}
```

I haven't defined getFees yet hence why it is commented out.
When I take away the &'s from them I get even more errors
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been sitting here fore hours going through it but just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: You should use `+` to concatenate strings not `<<`

Comment: And you are concatenating `int` and `Status` to a `string` -- it will not work by default

Comment: `&getCallNumber()` is incorrect. `getCallNumber()` returns a string, adding the & makes it a pointer to a string. Get rid of the &s before the function calls in your print line. You also probably want to use a stringstream to create an output string like that.

Comment: I had tried that and I get the error cannot add two pointers. When I remove the &'s from that one I get 21 different errors which starts with 
Error C2782 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> std::operator +(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &&,const _Elem)': template parameter '_Elem' is ambiguous a2p1

Comment: You shouldn't add & in front, that will be taking the address of the string, not the string itself.  And why not just `cout` it. And have you overloaded `operator <<` for the `Status` class

Comment: Honestly I did forget to overload the << operator for Status and cout never crossed my mind lack of sleep does that to you. I will get on that now. Thanks

Comment: `+` to concatente strngs, `<<` is (overloaded) operator in streams, a You don't use stream

Answer (score 1):

> my print line is :
>
> ```
> string printOutput = "Book #" << &getCallNumber() << ", title: " << &getTitle() << " by " << &getAuthor() << " pages: " <<
> > getNumPages() << ", status: " << getStatus() << ", fees: " /*<<
> > getFees()*/;
> ```

In C++, if you want to print something, You can simply `std::cout` it (given the things that you want to print have overloaded `operator<<` for `ostream`) --  No need to construct a `string` object first

```
std::cout << "Book #" << getCallNumber() << ", title: " << getTitle() << " by " 
<< getAuthor() << " pages: " << getNumPages() << ", status: " << getStatus() << ", fees: ";
```

And since `getStatus()` returns a `Status`, you should make sure the `Status` class has overloaded `operator <<` for the `ostream`. 
Note, no `&` sign in the front -- adding `&` will be taking the address of the `string`, not the `string` itself.

**UPDATE**

You can overload the `operator<<` anywhere you want. It doesn't need to be a `friend` function if it's not going to access the `private` part of the class. And given `Status` is a `enum class`, I would believe overloading it above `main` would be sufficient. And given

```
enum class Status { AVAILABLE, ON_LOAN, PROCESSED, MISSING, OVERDUE, };
```

You can do something like

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Status s) {
    switch(s)
    {
        case Status::AVAILABLE:
            os << "AVAILABLE";
            break;
        case Status::ON_LOAN: 
            os << "ON_LOAN";
            break;
        ....//And do the same thing for the other cases

    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: I'm having a problem with overloading the << Operator. I'm not allowed to change the header file we were given for this program where the status class is located. So adding friendship is impossible. Any ideas on how to solve that
 enum class Status {
    AVAILABLE,
    ON_LOAN,
    PROCESSED,
    MISSING,
    OVERDUE,
};
is what the Status class looks like in the header